# How do you properly overwrite instructions loaded in memory from an injected DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dll

I am writing a dynamic link library to be injected into a singleplayer game on Windows and serve as a "cinematic tool" (overwriting camera transforms, timescale, etc.):

Let's say that the base address for the game executable in the virtual memory space is `0x140000000` and there's an instruction at `foo.exe+0x10D64B81` that I want to overwrite. The instruction is `mulss xmm1,[rdi+0000027C]` (`F3 0F 59 8F 7C 02 00 00`, 8 bytes), the modified code to be written starting at that address/offset is `xorps xmm1,xmm1 / nop / nop / nop / nop / nop` (`0F 57 C9 90 90 90 90 90`, 8 bytes).

I have the following implementation (simplified for demonstration purposes):

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

using byte = unsigned char;

class FunctionMod
{
public:
    FunctionMod(void* baseAddress, size_t offset, const byte* code, size_t length)
        : m_BaseAddress(baseAddress), m_Offset(offset), m_ModifiedCode(), m_Length(length)
    {
        m_ModifiedCode = new byte[m_Length];
        std::copy(code, &code[m_Length], m_ModifiedCode);
    }

    ~FunctionMod() noexcept
    {
        delete[] m_ModifiedCode;
    }

    void overwrite() const
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Length; i++)
            *((byte*)m_BaseAddress + m_Offset + i) = m_ModifiedCode[i];
    }

private:
    void*  m_BaseAddress;
    size_t m_Offset;
    size_t m_Length;
    byte*  m_ModifiedCode;
};

...

DWORD64 functionOffset  = 0x10D64B81;
byte    functionCode[8] = { 0x0F, 0x57, 0xC9, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90 };

FunctionMod guiMod(
    (void*)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    functionOffset,
    functionCode,
    sizeof(functionCode)
);

guiMod.overwrite();
```

This works perfectly fine with other offsets and instructions, but for some reason, this particular example consistently writes `0F **A2** C9 90 ...` to the respective memory location, instead of `0F **57** C9 90 ...`, translating to `cpuid \ leave \ nop ...` and thus crashing the process.

I'm losing my mind trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. There doesn't seem to be a point where 0x57 could somehow become 0xA2. I have verified that the memory is copied correctly in the class constructor, printing out the bytes to a console instead of writing them to the actual memory also gives the expected result, the pointer arithmetic checks out as well. The only time the 0xA2 is written is when I dereference the pointer and write to the actual memory.

Anyone, please, any ideas?

EDIT: Overwriting the memory from a different process  running as administrator with `WriteProcessMemory` works properly, but I "need" (it would be much less work) to do this from the dll.

Comment: FlushInstructionCache ?

Comment: @Anders Thanks for the tip, I tried calling that after updating the instructions in `FunctionMod::overwrite()`, still the same thing happens as before. I don't think it's a cache issue, it happens consistently across process and system restarts.

Comment: This sounds very strange indeed, perhaps it has to do with some protection mechanism (maybe utilizing self-modifying code)? Did you try suspending the games' other threads before writing, and then resuming? If you immediately write and then read again, what do you get back? If you attach a debugger and set a hardware breakpoint on writing on that address, does it fire a second time after you wrote to it? If you break in your debugger before the write and then single-step through the instructions, do you see 57 or A2 written after stepping past the write?

Comment: If it's indeed that particular byte in the code that's problematic because something else writes to it, you could also try to work around this problem by putting an instruction there that can tolerate getting that byte changed, for example `cmp al, 0` (`3C 00`) which would then probably turn into `cmp al, 0xA2` (`3C A2`) but that wouldn't matter because you are not interested in the comparison anyway (assuming you can live with the flags register getting clobbered a bit). So you'd encode `cmp al, 0; xorps xmm1, xmm1; nop; nop; nop` instead.

Comment: @CherryDT Self-modifying code is not at work here and nothing else is writing to the memory region either (otherwise the method with `WriteProcessMemory` would fail too, I think, and also I was inspecting the memory with Cheat Engine the whole time and didn't notice any changes/writes), but suspending the other threads did the trick. Thanks a lot for your help (and see my answer for the full story) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Pausing and resuming threads

Thanks to [@CherryDT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1871033/cherrydt) for pointing this out — **suspending the other threads** of the process before writing to memory and then resuming them **did the trick**.

The function whose instructions I'm overwriting is one that calculates and modifies HUD opacity. In hindsight, it seems kind of obvious that a function like this would be called very often (probably in the game loop, so at least once per every frame) and so my hypothesis is that **one of the game threads probably got to the function while my thread was still writing to that memory region**, therefore encountering invalid instructions and stopping execution.

I still don't know why the magical A2 byte appeared every time, but even when I tried writing different instructions or changed their order (which, strangely, wrote the bytes I wanted correctly), I still got a crash afterwards.

#### Hence the solution:

```cpp
void FunctionMod::overwrite() const
{
    pauseThreads();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_Length; i++)
        *((byte*)m_BaseAddress + m_Offset + i) = m_ModifiedCode[i];
        
    flushInstructionCache(); // in my experience not necessary but better be safe than sorry
    resumeThreads();
}
```

where both `pauseThreads` and `resumeThreads` first get a list of thread ids using Toolhelp32 as decribed [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060223-14/?p=32173) (make sure to exclude the id of the calling thread, i.e. `GetCurrentThreadId()`) and then use `OpenThread`
with the `THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME` access flag to get the thread handles and finally `SuspendThread` and `ResumeThread` to pause and resume thread execution. Phew!

Comment: Just a side note: Since you only replaced one instruction, this suffices, but if you ever have this issue with more than one instruction and you also suspend the threads then, then you need to additionally check with `GetThreadContext` whether any thread has its `rip` in the middle of the code you want to replace, and if it has, you could simply resume that thread and then immediately suspend it again and try again until the instruction pointer is longer is in that area. Otherwise you'd still change the carpet under its feet and probably crash.

Comment: @CherryDT Good point!

Comment: Of course, if you ever have to replace a `call` instruction plus some following instructions, this problem gets worse because now you may have the `rip` inside of the called function or even further down the call stack, and you'd have to go some other clever route, depending on the exact circumstances.